# How to correct for heteroskedasticity in fixed effects panel regression with correction for clustered standard error?

Tags: panel-data, heteroscedasticity, clustered-standard-errors

I am a student at RSM and I have a question regarding my regression analysis for my thesis as I have encountered issues I do not know how to deal with.

I have performance data (dependent variable) of companies in 13 different countries, all of which are the ones I wish to regress against financial liberalization factors (independent variables). My time period run from 1980 to today. Each company has multiple observations over different time periods, after correcting for firm fixed effects as I wish to run a regression with *all* my data for all countries in one.

I have also included the clustering standard errors for the companies as the observations for one company are clustered. However, the issue now is that all my models appear to highly suffer from heteroskedasticity.

After reading numerous econometric papers which are too technical for me to understand, I am clueless as to how I should proceed.

Could you please advice me on how to fix this problem?

Comment: How did you cluster the standard errors? Many of the canned approaches use cluster-robust standard errors, which also take heteroskedasticity into account.